# Show that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \leq \limsup_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}?$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> If $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that
>   $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} < \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\tag{$\ast$}$$
>   for any $y \in (x,x+h)$, then
>   $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \leq \limsup_{p \to 0+}\frac{f(x+p)-f(x)}{p}?$$

Actually, I'm trying to prove that if
$$\limsup_{p \to 0+}\frac{f(x+p)-f(x)}{p} \leq k$$
so,
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \leq k$$
for $a\leq x<x+h\leq b$. This is only part of an question.

I (think that I) showed it without $(\ast)$, but it was very different from the rest of the question. Just for preciosity, I'd like to prove it using $(\ast)$. Can someone help me?

Comment: You have $h$ within a limit and outside the limit.  Perhaps you want an alternate variable.

Comment: I edited. Thank you!

Comment: You can rephrase your problem as: if $g(p) < g(h)$ for all $0 < p < h$ then $\limsup_{p \to 0^+} g(p) \le g(h)$. Can you work that out?

Comment: I dont know if I understand. With that, would not I get the opposite inequality? If I write $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = \frac{f(x+p)-f(x)}{p} = g(p)$, I want to prove that if $g(h) < g(p)$ then $g(h) \leq \limsup_{p\to 0+}g(p)$.

Comment: I got the direction on the inequality wrong. The idea is exactly the same.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that for $y \in (x,x+h)$,

$$k < \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} < \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$

We then have for  $\delta > 0$,

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}  \leqslant  \sup_{y \in (x,x+\delta)}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \\ \implies\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}  \leqslant  \lim_{\delta \to 0+}\sup_{y \in (x,x+\delta)}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = \limsup_{y \to x+} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}, $$

leading to a contradiction

$$k < \limsup_{y \to x+}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}= D^+f(x) \leqslant k$$

Comment: The first time I did it using $\limsup _{x \to a}f(x) = \inf_{\delta > 0}\left(\sup_{0<|x-a|<\delta}f(x)\right)$ and so, adding $\epsilon$, we can eliminate the $\inf$, then changing $\delta$, we can eliminate the $\sup$. But I found it very disconnected with the rest of your development and so I proved using Umberto P's hint with similar arguments to the ones you used.